# BindingSource And Composite Properties

Tags: c#, winforms, list, data-binding, datagridview

I have a method that I call in a form that returns a List and then I throw that into a BindingSource and throw the BindingSource into a DataGridView. The Order class has a property called Items that contains a List.  My Order and Item class both implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

What I'm trying to do is that when a row is clicked in the DataGridView it pulls up the list of items associated with the order from it's Items property into another grid. I want to ensure that those items are 2 way binded to the grid but I can't call it the way I'd like to...

```
itemsGrid.DataSource = orderBindingSource[orderGrid.CurrentRow.Index].Items;
```

I can't access the properties of the list from within the BindingSource (After the . operator, Items is not an available option)... Any recommendations? I've tried using a `BindingList<Order>` and `BindingList<List<Order>>` but was getting implicit conversion errors. Any suggestions?

*EDIT: Ok I've managed to get the BindingList to work. I didn't know I had to add the list like this

```
orderList = new BindingList<Order>(Method To Retrieve List<Order>)
```

Aside from this, the first grid displaying the orders works and updates perfectly. The sub grid which contains the Order's Items bound like

```
itemsGrid.Datasource = orderList[ordersGrid.CurrentRow.Index].Items;
```

It displays properly. I don't have editing enabled as I have a few textboxes that are setup and each textbox is bound to the Item from the orderList of the currently selected row of the ordersGrid. I can update the data in the textboxes for the selected item in the subgrid but the changes when I leave the textbox, the sub grid's row for that item property edited does not update as I leave the textbox. It will, however, update if I select another item in the grid. How can I get it to update as I leave the textbox instead of having to click on another row in the grid?